# Get array of all words (split sentences) included in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have this array:

```
this.places = [{"full_name":"joe","title1":"teacher","description":"the best teacher"},
              {"full_name":"mary","title1":"student","description":"great student"}];
```

I need to get this:

```
this.items = [{"word":"joe"},{"word":"teacher"},{"word":"the"},{"word":"best"},{"word":"teacher"}, 
             {"word":"mary"},{"word":"student"},{"word":"great"},{"word":"student"} ];
```

I have this now:

```
 this.places.forEach(item => {
        this.items = results.concat(item.full_name.toLocaleLowerCase().split(" "))
            .concat(item.title1.toLocaleLowerCase().split(" "))
            .concat(item.description.toLocaleLowerCase().split(" "));    
      });
```

Result:

```
["joe","teacher","the","best","teacher","mary","student","great","student"];
```

Can you help me to get the complete final desired array?

Comment: are you trying to do something related to map/reduce for later? such as counting words in a book or library and their frequency... so now you can mapping and then later on you would reduce it to `{ joe:  12 }` for your 10 pages or for your book and then further reduce with other people's results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way with reduce:

```js
this.places = [
  {"full_name":"joe","title1":"teacher","description":"the best teacher"},             
  {"full_name":"mary","title1":"student","description":"great student"}
];

this.items = this.places.reduce((acc, place) => {
  Object.values(place).toString().split(/\s+|,/).forEach(word => acc.push({ word }));
  // This might be slightly faster
  // Object.values(place).toString().replace(/\w+/g, word => acc.push({ word }));
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(this.items);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
this.places = [{"full_name":"joe","title1":"teacher","description":"the best teacher"},
               {"full_name":"mary","title1":"student","description":"great student"}];

this.items = [];
for (const obj of this.places)
  for (const v of Object.values(obj))
    v.toLocaleLowerCase().split(/\s+/).forEach(w => this.items.push({word: w}));

console.log(JSON.stringify(this.items));
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
this.places.forEach(item => {
        this.items.push(`{"word": results.concat(item.full_name.toLocaleLowerCase().split(" "))
            .concat(item.title1.toLocaleLowerCase().split(" "))
            .concat(item.description.toLocaleLowerCase().split(" "))};    
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

Below solution works

```
this.places = [{"full_name":"joe","title1":"teacher","description":"the best teacher"}{"full_name":"mary","title1":"student","description":"great student"}];
this.items = [];   
this.places.forEach(el=>Object.values(el).toString().toLocaleLowerCase().split(/[ ,]+/).forEach(word =>this.items.push({word:word})));
console.log(this.items)
```